# Java Heap space error in Hadoop

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, memory

I have setup hadoop cluster with single node as
**OS** : CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406
**Hadoop** : 2.6.0
**Java** : 1.7

My problem is with hadoop heap memory. I am currently reading file of 50 MB in reducer setup step successfully, But when file is larger than that approx( 500MB ) it gives me "out of memory error". When i browse  through http:/ip_address:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview it gives me below information.

**Heap Memory used 282.52 MB of 471 MB Heap Memory. Max Heap Memory is 8.89 GB.**

More Description For Error:

```
Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=176
        Map output records=512299
        Map output bytes=26127249
        Map output materialized bytes=27151853
        Input split bytes=108
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=512299
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=87
        CPU time spent (ms)=4410
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=277155840
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=903360512
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=202375168
File Input Format Counters
        Bytes Read=846327
```

What is missing in the configuration. Can anybody please help me??

Comment: Can you increase the amount of heap you have?  Hadoop is designed for systems with many GB of memory e.g. tens or hundreds. How much memory does it use for 50 MB?  I suggest you make it 10x that.

Comment: Yes i increased it already to 8.89GB but even if for loading 500MB file its giving me error.

Comment: I would keep increasing it until you don't get an error.  How much memory did you use for 50 MB?

Comment: Hi Peter, Actually the problem is may be with setup previously i was using hadoop 1.2.1 with heap space 7.11GB in it. But with new setup same map_reduce job doesn't work. Why its so is very difficult to know since i was checking almost every configuration of hadoop since last 2 days. If you have any idea regarding it please let me know..

Comment: You can watch the process in jvisualvm to see how much it uses.